Sonata AdminType fields are not validated
I have two admins UserAdmin and UserSettingsAdmin. In the UserAdmin I added a AdminType field that embeds UserSettingsAdmin form fields:
// AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin.php

$formMapper
  ->add('settings', AdminType::class, [
    'label' => false
  ]);

// AppBundle\Admin\UserSettingsAdmin.php

$formMapper
  ->add('canBookUntil', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Gali rezervuotis iki',
    'choices' => $choices,
    'placeholder' => 'Darbo dienos pabaigos',
    'empty_data' => null
  ]);

Form is displayed correctly. UserAdmin contains UserSettingsAdmin form fields.
I added some assertions to canBookUntil field including validate() callback to test that validation works from parent form:
// AppBundle\Entity\User.php

/**
 * @var UserSettings
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserSettings", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
public $settings;

// AppBundle\Entity\UserSettings.php

/**
 * @var string|null
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Pasirinkite laiką.")
 */
private $canBookUntil;

// ...
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 * @param mixed $payload
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload): void
{
  $context->buildViolation('Įveskite laiką.')->atPath('canBookUntil')->addViolation();
}

Unfortunately, after UserAdmin form submit button click, the form error is not displayed.
Am I missing something?
I tried submitting UserSettingsAdmin form and error appears..
